# Import into Blender the files mentioned in an excel list

Tags: scripting

is it possible to import into Blender the files mentioned in an excel list?
For example the excel list could be saved in a folder called “resources”, and the same folder contains also different blender files.
I would like to have a main Blender file called “Scene”, and a python script that reads the name of the blender files mentioned in the first row of the excel file and import them into blender.
Then clean the scene and repeat the process for the second row etc.

Any advice?

Comment: Hello ! What exactly do you mean with "import" ? What type of files would need to be imported ?

Comment: i assume he meant this: contents of resources folder: a.blend, b.blend, scene.blend. Now scene.blend should run a script which imports all objects/materials etc into scene.blend from a.blend. Then probably render it, then clean all up and same with b.blend, is this right, where?

Comment: There is no easy way to directly read Excel files in python.  You can either export the Excel file as a comma-separated-values (CSV) file, or use a Python library like [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) to do the reading.  I recommend exporting to CSV.  But it is not clear what you mean by 'import'.  To blender, import means to bring non-blender files into a running blender instance.  If that's what you mean, yes, it's easy to do that provided there is an importer for the file type.

Comment: If you mean you want some or all of an existing blend file, Blender refers to that as 'appending' the contents.  This can be done also, but the technique is different.  It would help if you would give a more detailed example.

Comment: Thank you everyone for commenting.
I try to explain more in detail:

I have a folder containing:  
1) a Blender file called "scene" (that contains already a camera, , light, render settings etc)  
2) a folder called "renders", where the renders should be saved  
3) a folder calles "resources" containing many different blender files (called 01,02,03,04,05,06,07…)   
The python script selects all the Blender files in the row 2 of the excel file, load them into my blender file called "scene", renders a picture and saves it as 1.jpg in the folder called "renders" .

Comment: The script cleans the scene from the imported files.  
The script repeat the process for each individual row in the excel file (for all the rows in the excel file)